# Is there a way to install Anki Add ons programmatically?

Tags: python, anki

I would like to install Anki add-ons programmatically without resorting to the GUI, like "anki install 2055492159" or within python like:

```py
import anki

anki.addons.install("2055492159")
```

This way I would be able to use the CLI and create bash scripts to port my installation configurations between systems easily. I tried using the Python module anki with "pip install anki" but did not find anything related to Add-ons there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to install add-ons programatically, but the process is simple enough that you can include instructions. The Anki manual has instructions on how to install add-ons.